# How to user linux shell to comment out a spring xml?

Tags: xml, linux, shell, xml-parsing

I hava a spring.xml and I want to comment out one interceptor, what shell script should I use to comment out this config like bellow? In other words how should I add one line before a specific line, for example line 70. Thanks!

```
 70         <mvc:interceptor>
 71             <mvc:mapping path="/openapi/**"/>
 72             <bean parent="paramsEncryptInterceptor"/>
 73         </mvc:interceptor>

 70         <!--
 71         <mvc:interceptor>
 72             <mvc:mapping path="/openapi/**"/>
 73             <bean parent="paramsEncryptInterceptor"/>
 74         </mvc:interceptor>
 75         -->
```

**Solution**
I get done through inserting a comment String to a specific line like bellow:

```
sed -i '70i<!--' spring.xml
sed -i '75i-->' spring.xml
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am using "sed -i '70i<!--' spring.xml" to insert a line, and get it commented out this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following without a backreference:

```
$ sed -e '/<mvc:interceptor>/s/^/<!--\n/' \
-e '/<\/mvc:interceptor>/s/$/\n-->/' filename
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/stuff.txt
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/openapi/**"/>
    <bean parent="paramsEncryptInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptor>
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -e '/<mvc:interceptor>/s/^/<!--\n/' \
-e '/<\/mvc:interceptor>/s/$/\n-->/' dat/stuff.txt
<!--
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/openapi/**"/>
    <bean parent="paramsEncryptInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptor>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
sed 's/\(<mvc:interceptor\)/<!--\n\1/;s|\(</mvc:interceptor>\)|\1\n-->|' yourfile.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try out Vim editor

> vi yourfile.xml